# How Is Maven Helping me in the Spring Tutorial

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I followed [this Getting Started with Spring/Maven Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/#scratch) to well, get started with spring and maven. I thought Maven helps me with deploying libraries/dependencies etc.
But in the tutorial for maven, there are two libraries (`joda/hamcast`) already, which are not included in `IntelliJ`.   If I just follow the guide though, nothing works as its stated there, I have to manually download the `.jar` files and add them to my Project Structure.
What is to gain here or did I understand Maven wrong?

EDIT: You wanted additional information, which I will provide now to clarify things. Thanks for all the replies so far!
[image]
After adding the `joda dependecy` as stated by the tutorial, the first `maven compile` downloaded the `.jars`. Nevertheless, it is saying `"No sources to compile"` and `"BUILD SUCCESS"`. Still, in my project, LocalTime is still red and unknown, even after refreshing/rebuilding the project.
The "reimport" feature solved my problem, thanks everyone!

Comment: If you have downloaded them manually than you have an firewall/proxy issue....Have you tried to build on plain command line?

Comment: Once you've got the dependencies in your pom.xml, you shouldn't have to manually download the jar files.  Without knowing how far you got in the tutorial, it's hard to say why it's not working for you, though.

Comment: Also, saying "nothing works" isn't particularly helpful.  Please [edit] your question to indicate how far you got in the tutorial before one of the steps failed, and also exactly what the error/failure was in that step.

Comment: This worked on my station at home, where i build the project manually, but does not work on another pc.
So here is the updated link for my problem, I would appreciate if you guys check that out, too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275252/maven-downloads-dependecy-but-does-not-add-them-cannot-find-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Intellij Idea this can be accomplished by using "Reimport all Maven Projects" [image]